# Why cannot you use a 'f' suffix directly after an integer?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, literals

While writing a C++ application, I have found out that I cannot use the `f` suffix (e.g. `3f`) as Visual Studio shows me the following error: *"Literal operator not found"*. The problem, of course, disappears when I use the `.f` suffix(e.g. `3.f`). Why is that?

Comment: You are writing what C++ code?

Comment: @nick The only answer there that supports your contention in any way is wrong. All the others say there is no such thing as `.f`.

Comment: Aside: The `f` is not a _literal_ here.,  It is a _suffix_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the rules from the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.fcon):

```
floating-point-literal:
    decimal-floating-point-literal
    hexadecimal-floating-point-literal

decimal-floating-point-literal:
    fractional-constant exponent-part-opt floating-point-suffix-opt
    digit-sequence exponent-part floating-point-suffix-opt

fractional-constant:
    digit-sequence-opt . digit-sequence
    digit-sequence .

exponent-part:
    e sign-opt digit-sequence
    E sign-opt digit-sequence

floating-point-suffix: one of
    f  l  F  L
```

As you can see, the `.` has to be always included in a decimal floating point constant, if there is no exponent part.

The K&R book explains this as:

> Floating-point constants contain a decimal point ( 123.4 ) or an exponent ( 1e-2 ) or both; their type is double, unless suffixed. The suffixes f or F indicate a float constant; l or L indicate a long double .

So, the thinking is, that `f` or `l` modifies an already floating-point constant (`double`) to have the type of `float` or `long double`. The suffix itself doesn't make a non-floating-point constant to a floating-point constant.

Comment: Last part is the key: "suffix itself doesn't make a non-floating-point constant to a floating-point constant."

Answer (score 3):

> Why cannot you use a 'f' literal directly after an integer?

If `f` *suffix* was allowed after text forming an integer to become a floating point,  a problem would occur with hexadecimal integers/floating-point

```
0x1.23f  // this is a float
0x1p23f  // this is a float
0x123f   // If this now a float?  No, it remains an integer.
```

The `f` suffix changes the type of a floating point literal from the default of `double`.  In C, an `f` or `F` suffix does not make a floating point *literal* but a floating point *constant*.